# Mallet HMM Training Problems

Tags: java, mallet, hidden-markov-models

I am struggling at the moment with Mallet's ridiculously poor documentation regarding HMMs. I have managed to import the data into instances(adapted from the ImportExample.java snippet) and I was just wondering how they can be used to train an HMM model.
I first started by creating an HMM instance but I wasn't sure whether to go for:

> ```
>     HMM hmm = new HMM(instances.getDataAlphabet(), instances.getTargetAlphabet());
> ```

Or use the same data alphabet twice like so:

> ```
>     HMM hmm = new HMM(instances.getDataAlphabet(), instances.getDataAlphabet());
> ```

Either way when I get to

> ```
>     hmm.train(instances);
> ```

I get the following error:

> cc.mallet.types.FeatureVector cannot be cast to
>   cc.mallet.types.FeatureVectorSequence

I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this particular problem and thought it may be useful to others with the same problem. There is a solution within the examples package in mallet: http://hg-iesl.cs.umass.edu/hg/mallet/file/83adf71b0824/src/cc/mallet/examples/TrainHMM.java

The main problem was related to how you imported the data through the pipe. Also from what I can tell it helps if you data is in this format:

```
TOKEN  TAG 
TOKEN  TAG
```

I assuming you can have features in between the TOKEN and TAG but am not a 100% sure. If anyone knows of any good examples and documentation about using HMM within mallet, please let me know.